# Will default value specified in rails migration overwrite column values in the future?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a migration which adds a foreign key to the users table.

```
[timestamp]_add_group_id_to_users.rb
```

Inside this migration file, I'm specifying a default value for it:

```
def self.up
  add_column :users, :group_id, :integer, :default => 1
end
```

But what happens after a while when let's say a user has now `group_id: 4`
and another feature will be pushed to production?

Will all the migration files be run again? 
Will group_ids of users be overwritten?

Should I specify something like "overwrite it if group_id is nil but don't do it if it's not and if it's different from 1" ?

Comment: The default value is only used when no value is given

Comment: @YuryLebedev can you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: "When a new row is created and no values are specified for some of the columns, those columns will be filled with their respective default values."

Your existing data will not be altered by the default columns, the default value will only be set for new records with a null `group_id`.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/ddl-default.html

Comment: So if you need to explicetely set `group_id` to one for existing users with the null `group_id`, you need to set it manually with a data migration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Migrations are additive, means only new migrations will be executed.